# one_of(vector) inside mutate_each results in object not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a small data set called test where I want to perform some mutate operation on columns defined in a vector cm.

Install  and load some packages

```
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
require(dplyr)
```

First create the test data frame

```
test <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,1),
    col2=as.character(c(2,2)),
    col3=as.character(c(3,3)), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then we create the cm vector

```
 cm <- c("col2", "col3")
```

I can now select the columns in cm with

```
test %>% select(one_of(cm))
```

but when I want to perform an operation, say as.numeric I get an error.

```
> test %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), one_of(cm))
Error in one_of(vars, ...) : object 'cm' not found
```

I can paste the vector manually though

```
test %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), one_of("col2","col3")) %>% str()
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col1: num  1 1
 $ col2: num  2 2
 $ col3: num  3 3
```

Is this a bug or a feature? Am I missing something? Any other ways of doing it?

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: Here are some more information on the topic: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

Comment: I was able to use both versions. Thank you! Please write it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to install and load the package `lazyeval` and then you could use one of the following options:

```
require(lazyeval)
require(dplyr)
test %>% 
   mutate_each_(funs(as.numeric), interp(~one_of(cm), var = as.name(cm))) %>% 
   str()
```

Or, a shorter version:

```
test %>% mutate_each_(funs(as.numeric), cm) %>% str()
```

Both will do the same in this case.